# Percentage calculation for video download progress

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am downloading a video using Intent service successfully. However I am not able to show the progress of the download.

```
resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
```

Here, the problem I am facing is that, since the fileLength is an Integer and the length of my file is far exceding the Integer capacity. I tried the same with long, and still wont work.

I know about Big Integers in Java, but I think I am not seeing a more obvious answer.

## EDIT:

Here is the code, I am using an intent service to run the download and update the dialog through the receiver.

```
public void  onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     String urlToDownload       = intent.getStringExtra("url");
     String path                = intent.getExtras().getString(C.INTENT_VIDEO_PATH);
     String videoId             = intent.getExtras().getString(C.INTENT_VIDEO_ID);
     L.i("Path : "+path);
     ResultReceiver receiver    = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
           
            long fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);
            

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
                resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            L.i("Total :"+count);

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        //TODO: Update DB.
        
        VideoTable.updateVideoPath(videoId, path);
        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
        resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);
        receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
    
}
```

Comment: Long too did not work.

Comment: what does that mean? `(long) (total * 100 / fileLength)`, does not work but `(long) ((long)total * (long)100 / (long)fileLength)` should definitely work

Comment: Its still not working..

Comment: I would like to see the code

Comment: I have updated my question with my code @blackbelt..

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

```
8 Bit = 1 Byte
1024 Byte = 1 Kbyte
1024 KByte = 1 MegaByte
1024 MByte = 1 GigaByte
1024 GByte = 1 TeraByte
1024 Terabytes = 1 Petabyte
```

I hope it helps you

In java, file.length(), The method returns length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname.